# Installing Module wrapt says - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wrapt'

Tags: python, python-3.x, octoprint

I am trying to install octoprint on ubuntu 18 using python 3.7
The installation fails with the message:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wrapt'

I naturally tried installing

pip3 install wrapt

And it fails too with the same message. It looks like I am in a loop where I need wrapt, but wrapt needs itself.

please advise

Answer (score 2):

If your using an Anaconda Virtiual Enviorment try using `conda install wrapt` That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in my jupyterLab on windows . I tried to delete it directly from the local system ,for me it was anaconca/lib/site-packages/wrapt . then reinstalled it using `pip install wrapt` .
and it worked for me . . .